# Nested IIF statement

Tags: reporting-services, iif

Having trouble with a IIF statement.  Trying to print a line of text if the result does not match 2 criteria but I keep getting an error saying that an expression is expected

```
=IIF((Fields!item.Value LIKE '%ASR%') AND (Fields!item.Value LIKE '%SERVRC%'),Fields!item.Value, 'No Code')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

```
=IIF(InStr(Fields!item.Value, "ASR")>0 AND InStr(Fields!item.Value, "SERVRC")>0, Fields!item.Value, "No Code")
```

You cannot use SQL syntax in an Expression in Report Services.

You can find examples of the available functions within Report Builder and here;
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx#VisualBasicFunctions